# monitor directly into a blade?

Tags: blade-server, ilo, keyboard-video-mouse

I have an iLO blade enclosure with a few blades in it.

Is there anyway to plug a monitor directly into a blade? keyboard and mouse would also be required.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you use HP blades, then there is a special cable with VGA, USB and Serial port.
Throw this cable you can connect your KVM directly to your blade.

Comment: they are HP, what is the name of this cable?

Comment: For completeness sake, it's the same with the Dells. There's a dongle that plugs into the front of each blade if you don't want to use the chassis KVM.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the cable is "HP c-Class Blade SUV(Serial, USB, VGA) Cable" if you have blade of c-Class (for example c7000 or c3000).

http://hpproliant.blogspot.com/2010/12/suv-cable-hp-blade-server.html